# Number of intervals that contains a given query point

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, intervals

I know a similar question exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062568/given-a-set-of-intervals-find-how-many-intervals-contain-a-point). My question is also same that I have N intervals (some possibly overlapping some even same). Then Q point queries are given and I need to tell how many intervals contains this point.

I tried to develop my algorithm by sorting the end point array then counting the number of overlapped interval by +1, -1 trick as mentioned in an answer. But after performing the binary search what I should do? Because its not always the case that the corresponding index of the prefix sum array is the answer.

```
e.g. 
Intervals are : [1,4] [5,7] [6,10] [7,13]
sorted end point array : [1,4,5,6,7,7,10,13]
+1/-1 array : [1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1]
prefix sum array : [1,0,1,2,3,2,1,0]

Query : 10
my algorithm gives 1 (corresponding prefix array)
but actual ans should be 2.
```

How should I fix my algorithm?

Comment: How many intervals can you have? How big can the end points be?

Comment: @juvian N<=1000 and end points are less than 1000000

Comment: Why would actual answer be 3? Only [5, 7] and [6, 10] contain 6

Comment: You are right. But still check for q=10 it gives 1 but should give 2. Editing the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no good answers in the question you linked, so:

First:

1. Put the entry and exit positions of each interval into separate arrays.  (if you are using closed intervals then exit position is end position + 1, i.e., in [4,6], entry is 4, exit is 7.
2. Sort the arrays.

Then, for each point p:

1. Binary search in the entry array to find the number of entry positions <= p.
2. Binary search in the exit array to find the number of exit positions <= p.
3. The number of intervals that contain the point is entry_count - exit_count

NOTE that the number of positions <= p is the index of the first element > p.  See: [Where is the mistake in my code to perform Binary Search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38258457/where-is-the-mistake-in-my-code-to-perform-binary-search/38258974#38258974) to help you get that search right.

For your example:

```
Intervals: [1,4], [5,7], [6,10], [7,13]
Entry positions: [1,5,6,7]
Exit positions: [5,8,11,14]
Entry positions <= 6:  3
Exit positions <= 6: 1
Intervals that contains 6:  3-1 = 2
```

Comment: I like this solution more, just need to be careful when doing the binary search when having multiple start or end points at same place.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your intervals are [] instead of [), and the answer probably was made for the latter . First transform your end indendexes to value -1.

After this + "compressing" repeated coordinates you should have:

```
 points = [1,5,6,7,8,11,14]
 sums = [1,0,1,1,-1,-1,-1]
 accumulated = [1,1,2,3,2,1,0]
```

Then for a query, if query < points[0] or query > points[max] return 0. If not, binary search over points to get index and the answer lies on accumulated[index].

Comment: @SujanDutta binary search = match highest point that is lower or equal to query. In this case it means 8, so the index is 4 and accumulated[4] is 2

Comment: Now I understood.